# Opencv return fps as 0.0

Tags: python, opencv, frame-rate

I try to get fps of a video and camera capture. However, when I open video the fps is correct but for camera capture always returns 0.
I'm using Opencv version 4.5.5 
Here is my related code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")
cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

result = 25.0

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap_fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
```

result = 0.0,

The only difference between in real inputs.

What should I do, please help me!

Comment: while video *files* may have a fps, webcams just deliver as fast as they can. dont expect a number for this

Comment: first check that the camera stream is actually opening with`video.isOpened()` if this returns `False` then the issue is with your camera (possibly `0` isnt the web cam stream). Alternatively you may need to uninstall/reinstall OpenCV

Comment: I'm watching video input at the same time, so the video is open.

Comment: if I change cv2.CAP_DSHOW that I got fps values. Should be a reason.